# Return ID of column from table with mysql_insert_id

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mysql-insert-id

```
$sql="INSERT INTO survey (user, title, description, opta, optb,optc,optd,time) VALUES ('$user','$title', '$dis', '$a' , '$b', '$c', '$d','timespan')";
if (mysqli_query($con,$sql))
 {
  echo "Success";
 }
 else
  {
  echo "Error: " . mysql_error();
  }
  echo $id = mysql_insert_id();

mysqli_close($con);
```

I want to return id of column from table, but it returns 0. why? and also how can i fix this problem? thanks in advance

Comment: Might you by chance have forgotten to add a `$` to `'timespan'`? I.e. `'$timespan'` Plus what John mentions in his answer. This isn't rum & coke btw, as in "*they don't mix*" ;-)

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` during development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing `mysql` and `mysqli` functions. Change:

```
echo $id = mysql_insert_id();
```

to

```
echo $id = mysqli_insert_id($con);
```

---

You also need to change `mysql_error()` to `mysqli_error()`

Not doing so, will not signal any possible errors found.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Oh, yeah. That, too. ;)

Comment: It's a winner! I told you we make a great team ;-)